# How can i add a readonly attribute to a declarations file?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a declarationsfile for a library that doesnt exist yet, but there are some classes in there that have readonly attributes. How can i put that in the declaration?

Answer (score 5):

Strangely, you can't specify getters and setters on interfaces or on ambient declarations.

The closest you can get is:

```
interface Test {
    Prop: number;
}

class Example implements Test {
    private prop: number;

    get Prop() :number {
        return this.prop;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't prevent the implementation from allowing a setter and in the context of an ambient declaration it wouldn't prevent the caller from attempting to set the value.

Comment: Oops, that 'doesnt exist yet' referred to the declarationsfile, not the library (web audio api) ;)

Comment: But thanks for the answer, what would happen if someone used the declarationsfile in a project targeted at <5 ?

Comment: You can only use get and set in TypeScript for ECMAScript 5 and above - I imagine this restriction would also apply to definitions. The concept of a read only property doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the difference between adding the declare keyword or the interface/class difference. I know the difference between those ;) but what difference does it make in a declarationsfile? I just have all my stuff there as such:


    interface AudioContext
    {
    }

Comment: Hmmm, i cant get that to work. When i do...

     interface AudioContext()
     {
          get sampleRate():number;
     }

... i get the error "Expected ';'" on the word samplerate.   (arg, why dont my four indentation-spaces work)

Comment: This is a bummer. lib.d.ts is also like this:
https://github.com/cloud9ide/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts#L1157-L1160

Comment: @SteveFenton "The concept of a read only property doesn't exist." - how about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze ?

Comment: @SebastianLasse ... in TypeScript interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

With TypeScript 2.0 you can now declare readonly properties, for example

```ts
interface Point {
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;
}

var p1: Point = { x: 10, y: 20 };
p1.x = 5;                            // Error, p1.x is read-only

var p2 = { x: 1, y: 1 };
var p3: Point = p2;                  // Ok, read-only alias for p2
p3.x = 5;                            // Error, p3.x is read-only
p2.x = 5;                            // Ok, but also changes p3.x because of aliasing
```

see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript) for more details.