# How can I declare a readonly property in a declarations file?

Tags: typescript

[The following](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20ns%20%7B%0A%09interface%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) doesn't seem to compile:

```
declare namespace ns {
    interface Test {
        readonly x: number;
    }
}
```

with:

> Cannot find name 'readonly'.
>   Property or signature expected.

nor does [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20ns%20%7B%0A%09interface%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A):

```
declare namespace ns {
    interface Test {
        const x: number;
    }
}
```

with:

> Property or signature expected.

Comment: The playground uses TS 1.8. The modifier `readonly` will be a feature of TS 2.0.

Comment: @Paleo Can you include a source for this, and write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is compiled without error by TypeScript 2.0:

```
declare namespace ns {
    interface Test {
        readonly x: number;
    }
}
```

The current release is 1.8. In order to test with the next version, on a local installation: 1/ install the nightly build of TypeScript with `npm install typescript@next`, then 2/ execute the compiler: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc your-file.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a `value` to a `property` in an `interface` in TypeScript.
So how would you set a `readonly` variable if you are not allowed to initially set it.

You can take a look at the answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471239/typescript-constants-in-an-interface) how you could solve this using a `module` instead:

```
module MyModule {
    export const myReadOnlyProperty = 1;
}

MyModule.myReadOnlyProperty= '2'; // Throws an error.
```

---

### Update

It seems you have to wait for `TypeScript 2.0` for this, which will have `readonly` properties then:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532

Comment: _You can't assign a value to a property in an interface in TypeScript._ True, but I can assign a value to the property of an object that implements the interface, and in this case I want to prevent that. _So how would you set a readonly variable..._, this is for an ambient declaration, which means I am not setting the property's value; that is being done by the library.

Comment: @ZevSpitz true, sorry i kinda responded to fast without thinking enough ;) This seems to be a similar question, but the answer won't help you out much i guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796751/how-can-i-add-a-readonly-attribute-to-a-declarations-file